# Installing Package with CocoaPods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to install the Charts package to use with CocoaPods and it keeps saying "No such module 'Charts'".

If I added the pod 'Charts' in the podfile, and did a pod install and the files are there in Xcode, how come it still gives me an error when I try to import Charts?

Do I still need to do the steps below? Or does CocoaPods do it for me?

Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project
Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework

My pods file looks like this now:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you open the `.xcworkspace` that's generated from `pod install` in your directory instead of the `.xcodeproj` file

Comment: Please post the contents of your Podfile

Comment: @Simon Yes, I opened the .xcworkspace instead of the .xcodeproj

Comment: I think it may be because my project is still on Swift 3.2. Is there a way to make the pod file install Charts for Swift 3.2 instead of Swift 4?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to hit <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> to build, then the error will go away. The other solution is to hit `Product > Build`.

[image: build]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was developing an app for an older platform. The CocoaPod I sourced supported Swift 4 but I was developing for Swift 3. When I sourced the last Swift 3 version of the pod, the "No such module" error was no longer there. Try the following line in your Podfile:

```
pod 'Charts', '3.0.3'
```

instead of the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

try installing it manually moving the complete charts folder to your project, or downloading using carthage, it's way more cleaner using carthage than cocoapods because it doesn't create you a .xcworkspace like cocoapods.